# Question based on pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> There are $126$ boxes containing apples. The number of apples in each box lies between $120$ and $150$ (inclusive). Let $F(n)$ indicate the number of boxes containing $n$ apples and $m$ indicates the maximum value of $F(n)$ for any $n$. What could be the minimum possible value of $m$?

Pigeons$=126$

Pigeonholes$=31$

$m=126/31=5$

Maximum value=$5$.

How to find minimum?

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

If every value would be less than $5$, the sum would be at most $4\cdot 31=124$. Hence your $m=5$ is already the solution.

Note that $29$ times value $4$ and $2$ times value $5$ realizes the $126$ boxes.